# How to create custom android application class in Flutter?

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

```
class MyApplication : FlutterApplication() {


    @CallSuper
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AppSpector
                .build(this)
                .withDefaultMonitors()
                .run("***")
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)
    }

    private var mCurrentActivity: Activity? = null
    override fun getCurrentActivity(): Activity? {
        return mCurrentActivity
    }

    override fun setCurrentActivity(mCurrentActivity: Activity) {
        this.mCurrentActivity = mCurrentActivity
    }
}
```

I want to use Custom application class. But when other activity launched getting below error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter mCurrentActivity`

Comment: dow want to call java code, then you have to deal with the MethodChannel concept.

Comment: got any solution @shakthi S.P. Swain

Comment: No @MuthuS, I might handle through MethodChannel

Comment: oops..bad luck.. i am also waiting for some help on this.. Lemme check if i got let you know. Thanks